# Prevent parent View from responding to gestures made on child FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a `View` which is responding to gestures via `PanResponder` handlers.

In the `View`, I have a `FlatList` which is horizontal and is scrollable. The scroll events from the `FlatList` are bubbled up to the `View` which ends up handling them.

I have tried multiple combinations of things suggested in the [Gesture Responder System docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#capture-shouldset-handlers) including, but not limited to

- attaching own `PanResponder` handlers to the `FlatList`
- wrapping the `FlatList` in its own `View` with that handling the gestures
- trying to block the scroll event using `onScroll={_ => false}` on the `FlatList` (that probably is not how it is supposed to work anyway)
- setting captures off on the topmost `View` with `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={_ => false}` and move capture handler

Nothing seems to work, however.

This is the minimal code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {FlatList, PanResponder, Text, View} from 'react-native';

function _getFlatListItem ({item}) {
  return (
    <Text style={{fontSize: 100}}>
      {item.key}
    </Text>
  );
}

export default class ContainerComponent extends Component {
  constructor () {
    this._handleSwipe = this._handleSwipe.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      data: [{
        key: 1
      }, {
        key: 2
      }, {
        key: 3
      }, {
        key: 4
      }]
    };
  }

  _handleSwipe (event, gestureState) {
    // detect gesture here and do whatever
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: _ => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: _ => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: this._handleSwipe,
      onPanResponderTerminate: this._handleSwipe
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
        {/* ...other components here */}
        <FlatList data={this.state.data}
          horizontal
          renderItem={_getFlatListItem}
          scrollEnabled />
        {/* ...some other components here */}
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

I just want to not trigger the pan handlers for the `View` if the swipe is being done on the `FlatList`.

I am filtering out the events bases on the velocity of the swipe, but that just results in bad UX where unintended things happen for swipes.

Comment: Did you try using `pointerEvents` prop on the parent view and setting it to `box-none` while FlatList is panning and 'auto' otherwise?

Comment: No. That sounds like it might work. Trying.

Comment: I added `onPanResponderGrant`, `onPanResponderRelease` handlers to the FlatList which toggle the pointerEvents props. It works, very erratically though. It only works for some velocities. I am not sure if that is just the Simulator.